# Can not enable Windows SmartScreen. Says: "this setting is managed by your system administrator"

Tags: windows, windows-8, group-policy, control-panel

I can not enable my Windows SmartScreen on Windows 8.1

My PC is not joined to any domain.

[image]

I'm not talking about SmartScreen feature available in IE but the feature that is available in File Explorer.

***Control Panel > Action Center > Change Windows SmartScreen settings***

I searched in group policy but couldn't find anything that is preventing me from enabling it.

***Update 1:***

My user is a member of administrators group.

Other things work fine. When I try to change something that needs administrative permission, UAC window appears, but nothing here.

***Update 2:***

Group Policy setting looks OK.

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as an administrator?

Comment: I'm not logged in as administrator, but my user is a member of administrators group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start gpedit.msc, go to Computer config - Admin templates - all settings - turn on/off windows smartscreen and set to not configured so that you can change it.

[image: Smartscreen GPO]

Comment: It is set to not configured.

Comment: @AfshinGh try setting it

Comment: is there any other smartcreen setting configured? You can also run process monitor in background while launching the Windows SmartScreen options, and look which registry keys is the tool querying.

Comment: Setting it to "Enabled" and then changing it back to "Not Configured" made it work! I can now change SmartScreen setting freely. Thanks @chipperyman573 for forcing me to try it :)

Comment: @AfshinGh It started working after re-setting for me too: If it's already set to "Not Configured" set it to Enabled -> hit Apply button -> set back to "Not Configured" -> Apply<br>
This bug is also present in Windows 10 1511